# AWS Cognito RespondToAuthChallengeRequest : Missing required parameter Session

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-cognito

As per the documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_RespondToAuthChallenge.html the session parameter is optional.

```
Map<String, String> challengeResponses = new HashMap<String, String>();

        challengeResponses.put("USERNAME", "username");
        challengeResponses.put("SMS_MFA_CODE","code");
        challengeResponses.put("SECRET_HASH", secretHash);

        RespondToAuthChallengeRequest respondToAuthChallengeRequest = new RespondToAuthChallengeRequest()
                .withChallengeName(ChallengeNameType.SMS_MFA).withClientId("client_id")
                .withChallengeResponses(challengeResponses);

        RespondToAuthChallengeResult respondToAuthChallengeResult = null;
            respondToAuthChallengeResult = cognitoClient.respondToAuthChallenge(respondToAuthChallengeRequest);
```

I keep on getting the below exception when I dont add a session parameter to the request.

```
**Missing required parameter Session (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: ef8780a3-a5f3-4d54-aac5-2251deb7e932)**
```

Comment: I'm currently facing this issue and I agree; the documentation absolutely suggests this kind of request should be fine and given you posted this fairly recently I suspect it's a bug... may need to contact their support :(

Comment: I'll let you know though if I find a workaround. I'm wanting to use this in order to validate an OTP once the user is signed in such that they can subsequently disable their 2nd auth factor